# Error in the bootstrapping of cloudify 3.2.1

Tags: cloudify

1-  I am getting the following error when I try to bootstrap cloudify 3.2.1 on openstack. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 image, and I do not have the same problem with cloudify 3.2. Any idea what does the error mean? And how could I solve it?

```
            Requested: sudo sh ~/getdocker.sh
            Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "sudo sh ~/getdocker.sh" [attempt 1/6]
            2015-09-06 18:55:49 CFY <manager> [manager_bc1e1.start] Sending task 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_module_task' [attempt 2/6]
            2015-09-06 18:55:49 CFY <manager> [manager_bc1e1.start] Task started 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_module_task' [attempt 2/6]
            2015-09-06 18:55:49 LOG <manager> [manager_bc1e1.start] INFO: running task: cloudify_cli.bootstrap.tasks.bootstrap_docker
            2015-09-06 18:55:49 LOG <manager> [manager_bc1e1.start] INFO: preparing fabric environment...
            2015-09-06 18:55:49 LOG <manager> [manager_bc1e1.start] INFO: environment prepared successfully
            2015-09-06 18:55:49 LOG <manager> [manager_bc1e1.start] INFO: initializing manager on the machine at 192.168.144.152
            2015-09-06 18:55:49 LOG <manager> [manager_bc1e1.start] ERROR: Exception raised on operation [fabric_plugin.tasks.run_module_task] invocation
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/opt/virt_env/cloudify321/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/decorators.py", line 125, in wrapper
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
              File "/opt/virt_env/cloudify321/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric_plugin/tasks.py", line 89, in run_module_task
                return _run_task(task, task_properties, fabric_env)
              File "/opt/virt_env/cloudify321/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric_plugin/tasks.py", line 95, in _run_task
                return task(**task_properties)
              File "/opt/virt_env/cloudify321/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify_cli/bootstrap/tasks.py", line 311, in bootstrap_docker
                return post_bootstrap_actions(wait_for_services_timeout=15)
              File "/opt/virt_env/cloudify321/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify_cli/bootstrap/tasks.py", line 290, in post_bootstrap_actions
                port = ctx.instance.runtime_properties[REST_PORT]
            KeyError: 'rest_port'
            2015-09-06 18:55:49 CFY <manager> [manager_bc1e1.start] Task failed 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_module_task' -> 'rest_port' [attempt 2/6]
```

2-  It seems that the default installation for cloudify 3.2 and 3.2.1 is docker , Is it possible to install 3.2 or 3.2.1 from packages as 3.1 ?if yes , What should I fix in the manager blueprint?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to mix Cloudify versions with 3.1. 3.2+ offers more compatibility between versions.

The specific error posted above does not offer very helpful messaging for troubleshooting. I would recommend contacting the [Cloudify Users Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloudify-users) for support.

Comment: I did not mix the versions, I have tried to deploy CF 3.2.1 using CLI 3.2.1 and blueprint 3.2.1